# Smart card-only login

Tags: macos, catalina, smart-card

We were setting up to only allow user to login into mac using Yubikey by following this article https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208372

We are now able to login using Yuibikey but mac still allow to use other method to login (password, fingerprint) has anyone be able to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install a configuration profile with the "enforceSmartCard" key?

Comment: Yes we installed the profile

Comment: Please include your profile in the question - it might have an error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could follow the instructions [here](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/Smart_card-only_authentication_on_macOS.html) to set up "Smart card-only" mode. I had tried it myself and summarized some **key points** as follows:

1. Make sure that you have paired your Yubikey with macOS. You could run `sc_auth list` in Terminal to check;
2. After installing the profile, you'd better plug out your Yubikey and **log out** the current admin user.
3. Then plug in your Yubikey, just wait a second. The password input will change to PIN input. If Yubikey was plugged out, there'll be a note probably says"Smart card is needed".

Hope it helpful~ ^_^